# Is there a way to parse CSV files in python where fields can have return characters?

Tags: python, csv, eol

I have some data that came from a SAS dataset that we are porting over to a web-based system. I've been unable to use either the Panda's SAS or STATA imports due to various errors, so CSV seems to be the safest bet, but, due to the fact that it has return characters in some of the fields, it's not going easily with either the csv library nor Pandas.

Is this something that can be done without having to parse these files myself? They are correctly quoted (i.e. SAS added quote characters to the fields with these return characters, and escaped other double quotes, but both libraries' functions appear to see return characters as record terminators, which is incorrect behavior for this use case).

I've tried setting quotechar, escapechar, etc. It seems this is just the way the CSV readers work.

Here is a simple example. line['RSID'] should only ever contain integers, but it often has fragments of comments that were from the prior record.

This is for Python 2.7, csv.**version**==1.0

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

with open("screening.csv", 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, quotechar='"')

    for line in reader:
        print line['RSID']
```

Comment: Python's CSV module handles newline characters embedded in correctly quoted strings just fine. How exactly are you opening the file, creating the CSV reader object and reading it? Please add the relevant parts of your code that are currently failing to your question, and mention the Python version since that's highly relevant here.

Comment: reader = csv.DictReader(file, quotechar='"')  -- That's one of the many permutations I've tried. When I iterate over the file and print out the 2nd column (which should be an integer), I get a number of entries which are from prior records. Are the return characters supposed to be escaped even though the field is correctly enclosed in quotes?

Comment: OK, so you're either not using binary mode or not setting the newline parameter correctly. Please, as stated before, name your Python version so we can determine which of the two errors it is. Also, please don't use the comments to post code; [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37442150/edit) your question instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "not setting the newline parameter" correctly? I don't see an option for that except for writing CSV files. These should be terminated by unix EOLN.

Comment: I see now that a very simple example works. Clearly SAS' CSV output is mangled somehow. It looks fine by eyesight...but, who knows.

Comment: OK, the newline parameter is only relevant in Python 3, and in the code you posted, you're doing everything right. You might want to check an entry where you get garbled fields and look at that part of the file with a hex editor. Incorrectly escaped quotes could also play a role in this - a literal quote in a CSV field should be escaped by doubling, not with a backslash - maybe that's something to look out for?

Comment: No, they escape double quotes with double quotes (so ,""" is possible). I'm trying to identify exactly which column has all this chatter so I can look at it more easily (there are hundreds of columns in this table). Hopefully, I'll find the culprit. Should I delete the question, since it's obviously not relevant to the actual problem I'm experiencing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly - the text `I "love" Lucy` should become `"I ""love"" Lucy"`...

Comment: yeah, but if a line starts with a quote, you'll get stuff like a comma followed by 3 double quotes. It turns out that SAS selectively chooses random fields to export in quotes. So, using an alternate method to write CSV files actually works. I suspect they only enclosed it in quotes if it had a comma in it or something silly like that.